# Vue CLI 3 - npm run serve vs serve -s dist

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I've a simple vue app created with vue cli 3. When I use `npm run serve` command over VS Code I can  display application over http://localhost:8080 with no problem. I'm using following commands to serve dist folder over localhost.

```
npm run build
serve -s dist
```

After above commands, I supposed to display application over http://localhost:5000 but I'm getting following error on IE11 and application works fine on chrome.

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
paginator.js (11,1)
```

Here is the paginator.js codes which IE11 gives error.

```
11 class Paginator {
12  constructor(screen) {
13    this.pointer = 0;
14    this.lastIndex = 0;
15    this.screen = screen;
16  }
```

What is `npm run build` doing and why does application run with no error after `npm run serve` command but does not run after `npm run build` command in IE11?

I have polyfills installed so that I can use application on IE11 after `npm run serve` and here is my script tag from PolyFill.io

```
<script crossorigin=anonymous src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Symbol%2Ces2015%2CArray.from"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`npm run build` minifies/compacts your source, and creates a `dist` subfolder.  Your issue is likely that IE11 isn't able to handle the minified JS.

Minified JS looks like this:

```
(function(t){function e(e){for(var n,r,l=e[0],i=e[1],c=e[2],p=0,u=[];p<l.length;p++)r=l[p],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,r)&&o[r]&&u.push(o[r][0]),o[r]=0;for(n in i)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(i,n)&&(t[n]=i[n]);d&&d(e);while(u.length)u.shift()();
```